# Hyperlink recognition in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink

I am receiving a hyperlink from my server that's formatted pretty much like the following example:

```
[link][1]

[1]: https://www.google.com
```

This is the basic way to embed a hyperlink to a text.

Now, I want to show this on my iOS app in the proper way like this [link](http://www.google.com), ideally by using UILabel or UITextView. I know UITextView can detect links, but it doesn't format hyperlinks itself.

Is it possible to achieve this functionality in iOS? And if yes, what would be the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I had to work with hyperlinks I did this

```
let link = "<a href=\"\(link)\">Link</a>" 

let aLink = try! NSMutableAttributedString(data: link.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)

self.textView.attributedText = aLink
```

This worked for me

Comment: Had to pre-format my string to match the HTML formatting instead of markdown. And it started working then. Thanks

Comment: it detects the link but I when I click it nothing happened.. do you know why @danialzahid94 ??

Comment: @danialzahid94 We need to select the Link to Data Detectors to make it work.. but do you know why the text is tiny and I cannot edit it?